# How can add a file reference and set that file's target automatically using the post install portion of the Podfile?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have a project employing CocoaPods in which one of my pods requires a .framework file to be added as a reference to the Pods project after it is generated by `pod update`. The .framework file is located in the main project directory for now, and I'm adding a reference to it. Currently, I can go into the project navigator in Xcode after building the pods, right click and add the file to the project. I then have to select the framework file and set it's target to the pod that needs to make use of it.

In order to allow my CI server to build automatically, I'm attempting to automate the process of adding the file and selecting its target by using the post_install hook in the Podfile. That's where I'm running into issues.

I've managed to add the file reference to the group for the actual Pod, but this seems to not work as the files in that pod seem to expect to be importing a framework from outside its group. When I add the file reference manually to the Pods project but not within the actual group for the Pod in question, it works fine.

**First question:**
Is there a proper way to add a file reference to the Pods project itself without having to add it to a specific Pod's group? Or perhaps a way to create a new group for the file reference when adding it?

**Second question:**
How would I go about setting the target for the file once it is added to the Pods project automatically?

This is the code that adds the file reference to the Pod group itself:

```
post_install do |installer|
    dir = Dir.pwd + '/app/VPX.framework'
    group = installer.pods_project.pod_group('OGVKit')
    installer.pods_project.add_file_reference(dir, group)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the second by getting a reference to the target and adding the file reference to it. Here is the tl;dr; solution

```
post_install do |installer|

    dir = Dir.pwd + '/app/VPX.framework'

    project = installer.pods_project

    group_name = 'OGVKit'

    group     = project.pod_group(group_name)
    reference = project.add_file_reference(dir, group)

    project.targets.select { |target| 
      target.add_file_references([ reference ]) if target.display_name.eql? group_name
    }

end
```

here's a little breakdown:

```
project.add_file_reference(dir, group)
```

This returns a PBXFileReference, this just represents a reference to a file in the file system.

We can use this reference to add it to the build target.

```
project.targets.select { |target|
```

Loop and iterate over the available targets

```
target.add_file_references([ reference ]) if target.display_name.eql? group_name
```

The target `add_file_references` accepts an array of `PBXFileReference` objects, great, we can use the one we have previously obtained.

Cocoapods target name is the same as the group name, so we just need to perform a conditional check validating this.

Hope this helps.